# How do I update existing STDOUT?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout

I need to print a bunch of strings to STDOUT. Instead of each string going on a newline, though, I want to have just one line that gets *updated* with each new string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -n foo
echo -n bar
echo -n baz
echo quux

echo -n 55555
echo -ne '\r'4444
echo -ne '\r'333
echo -ne '\r'22
echo -e '\r'1
```

Comment: Just make sure it is being interpreted by bash, a [POSIX shell will simply echo the `-ne` as well](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/echo.html) (but it will interpret the escaped characters).

Comment: For better portability, use printf(1) instead.

Comment: @camh: can you explain further the portability issue?

Comment: @tokland: dreamlax provided the necessary explanation. You simply cannot rely on consistent behavior from `echo`, whereas `printf` is more powerful and does not have that problem.